# Relative position for div with a keyframes break the animation

Tags: css

In my twig, I have div which has a class with a keyframe animation (moving border), it's working fine with an absolute position, but I'm in a context where I will add multiple div for each object related to my user.

But when I set my CSS style to relative, my animation is no more, I tried many things (without success), but there is something I'm missing, from my understanding keyframes (and clip: rect) should be positioned on the div position.

Here's my working block code:

```
{% block name %}
<style>
    .bb::before,
    .bb::after,
    .bb {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    .bb {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: auto;
        color: #69ca62;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(105, 202, 98, 0.5);
    }
    .bb::before,
    .bb::after {
        content: "";
        z-index: -1;
        margin: -5%;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px;
        animation: clipMe 8s linear infinite;
    }
    .bb::before {
        animation-delay: -4s;
    } 
    .bb:hover::after,
    .bb:hover::before {
        background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    @keyframes clipMe {
        0% {
            clip: rect(0px, 220px, 2px, 0px); // ligne du haut
        }
        25% {
            clip: rect(0px, 2px, 220px, 0px); // ligne de gauche
        }
        50% {
            clip: rect(218px, 220px, 220px, 0px); // ligne du bas
        }
        75% {
            clip: rect(0px, 220px, 220px, 218px); // ligne de gauche
        }
        100% {
            clip: rect(0px, 220px, 2px, 0px); // ligne du haut
        }
    }
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        background-color: #0f222b;
    }

    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    div {
        position:relative;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>
{% for i in 0..2 %}
    
    <div class="bb"></div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

You should be able to copy paste it in a twig and see it working. If you modify the first absolute, everything broke, and I really don't understand why, please help me understand.

At the end you can see a for ..., you can erase it if you want, it was just a way to show how I thought about implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution to my problem, you to have to put it in 2 div, and the parent one will be the one with the relative

```
    .animboxpospadding
    {
        padding-top: 250px;
        position:relative;
        margin: 50px;
    }

</style>
{% for i in 0..2 %}

<div class="animboxpospadding">    
    <div>
        <div class="animbox"></div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The code above is exactly the same, i just renamed "bb" for  "animbox"

Hope it's useful for someone

--- Edit :
I refined it, now you can have a variable size for your container, you just need to modify the size of the css variable `--box-width: 800px; --box-lenght: 200px;`
My css is now in a file dedicated to it :

```css
/*
The var() function is used to insert the value of a CSS variable.

The syntax of the var() function is as follows:
var(--name, value)
CSS variables can have a global or local scope.
 global scope, declare it inside the :root
 local scope, declare it inside the selector that is going to use it.
*/

:root {
    --box-width: 200px;
    --box-lenght: 200px;

    --box-animation-width: calc(var(--box-width) + 20px);
    --box-animation-lenght: calc(var(--box-lenght) + 20px);
}

.animbox::before,
.animbox::after,
.animbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.animbox {
    width: var(--box-width);
    height: var(--box-lenght);
    margin: auto;
    color: #69ca62;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(105, 202, 98, 0.5);
}

.animbox::before,
.animbox::after {
    content: "";
    z-index: -1;
    margin: -10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px;
    animation: clipMe 8s linear infinite;
}

.animbox::before {
    animation-delay: -4s;
}

.animbox:hover::after,
.animbox:hover::before {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

@keyframes clipMe {
    0% {
        clip: rect(0px, var(--box-animation-width), 2px, 0px); /*  ligne du haut */
    }
    25% {
        clip: rect(0px, 2px, var(--box-animation-lenght), 0px); /* ligne de gauche */
    }
    50% {
        clip: rect(calc(var(--box-animation-lenght) - 2px), var(--box-animation-width), var(--box-animation-lenght), 0px); /*  ligne du bas */
    }
    75% {
        clip: rect(0px, var(--box-animation-width), var(--box-animation-lenght), calc(var(--box-animation-width) - 2px) ); /* ligne de droite */
    }
    100% {
        clip: rect(0px, var(--box-animation-width), 2px, 0px); /* ligne du haut */
    }
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #0f222b;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.animboxpospadding {
    padding-top: 250px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="animboxpospadding">    
        <div>
            <div class="animbox"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```